# Como quitar slugs de algunas secciones de un sitio en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un sitio en wordpress, en cual ya cuenta con opciones de tema para configurar la url base del sitio, lo que necesito es quitar la url base cuando se seleccione una categoría, he probado con plugins pero no me da resultado.

Un ejemplo de como esta actualmente
www.ejemplo.com/base-url/slug-categorias/categoria1

Necesito dejarlo de esta manera
www.ejemplo.com/slug-categoria/categoria1

esto cuando se seleccione una categoria, pero también necesito hacer que al seleccionar un tag elimine por completo el slug base y el slug de etiquetas

Ejemplo
www.ejemplo.com/base-url/tag/slug-etiqueta

Necesito dejarlo asi
www.ejemplo.com/slug-etiqueta

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

En lo personal yo no recomendaría modificar tanto la estructura base de los permalinks de Wordpress, los cuales llevan años desarrollandose y perfeccionandose.
Me parece que si disminuyes los niveles de las url tienes mayor riesgo de que estas choquen entre sí. Cuidado con eso.

Aquí hay un artículo que detalle un poco lo de la estructura de permalinks y para que funciona y como funciona mejor

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/wordpress-permalinks

Answer (score 0):

Las bases se dan por estos motivos:

1. En el menú "Ajustes > enlaces permanente" han puesto esa base en
   duro.
2. Hay un post_type que lleva por nombre 'base_url'
3. Tu WordPress está alojado en una carpeta "base_url"

Uno de esos tres motivos es lo que causa ello. Para solucionar cada uno de ellos debes hacer lo sigueinte:

1. Borrar esa base y farle en guardar cambios
2. Aqui te explican como quitarlo
   https://cybmeta.com/eliminar-el-slug-de-la-url-de-un-custom-post-type
3. Ir a "Ajustes > Generales" y modificar la URL de WordPress